# Java Scanner Advise

Tags: arrays

This is just a question, please do not give me the answer. I need direction:

Assume `stdin` is an object reference to a `Scanner`, and `count` is an `int` that has been initialized to `0`:

1. Read integers from `stdin` counting how many integers you see in the range `0-50` inclusive.
2. Stop when you read an integer outside the range.
3. `count` should be updated to indicate how many integers you read before you encounter an integer outside the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop to control the range, and then just keep reading in and adding to the count. It would look something like this:

```
while nextInt() is in range:
  add 1 to count
```

It's really pretty simple, but takes some time to understand why. Basically, you have `count` and `stdin`. In the `while` loop condition, you check the next number from `stding` to see if it is in the proper range, and then add to `count` if it is.